# Elasticsearch global node which internally connects to entire cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a 8 node cluster. Our applications are pointing to one node in this cluster using Transport Client. Issue here is if that node is down, then the applications won't work. we've resolved this by adding all the other 7 node ip's in the Trasport client object.

My question here is, do we have any concept like global node which internally connects to cluster, to which i can point our applications, so that we don't have to restart all our applications whenever we've added a new node to cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Transport Client itself is a participant in ES cluster . You can consider setting ["client.transport.sniff",](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) true in Transport client which will detect new nodes in cluster.

Comment: Fine, but we cannot keep on adding the new nodes to the transport client whenever a node got added to cluster right...So, If we have a concept of global node which connects to all nodes in a cluster, then we don't have to worry about restarting the applications.

Comment: You dont have to . sniff setting enables transport client itself to probe and discover new nodes in cluster.

Comment: Okay. let me understand one thing, If i mention only one node in my transport client object then what happens when that node went down? Will the application still connected to cluster or not? if not, is there any other way to resolve this instead of mentioning all nodes in the transport client object?